# how to change ruby path from /usr/bin/ruby to /usr/local/bin/ruby

Tags: ruby

reading around the various ruby install tutorials it's required to change path from /usr/bin/ruby to /usr/local/bin/ruby but i cant seem to be able to do it. Ultimately i want to install Ruby 1.9.2, should i uninstall 1.8.7 or what? i tried to install Ruby 1.9.2 with macports, the installation seemed to go ok, but i cant find the new version, i seem to be stuck with 1.8.7

```
iMac:~ rebel$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

rebel$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

.profile
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

From your shell I notice you are on a Mac. If that's true, I recommend you to have a look to [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew). Then follow the instructions and install RVM for Ruby. With RVM you don't need to uninstall ruby, you can have several versions encapsulated in their own directory. You simply switch from one version to another according to your needs.

For example you can have ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.0.1 in one setup and in another one you can have ruby 1.8.7 with rails 2.3.8...

In Mac, Homebrew with RVM is the easiest way...

Homebrew installation:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation

Here is a nice screencast with RVM:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm

Comment: +1: I'm working with RVM, too and it works great. This is the official site if you need a guide: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/